# Unable to retrieve DisplayName name and PhotoUrl from firebase, always returning null, Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, networkimageview

I am trying to retrieve the displayName name photoUrl from firebase as i have created a user using google sign in and i want to use the display photo and display name as that of google account.

```
child: ListTile(
              title: Text("${user.displayName}"),
              subtitle: Text("${user.username}"),
              leading: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: user.photoUrl,
                placeholder: (context, url) => circularProgress(),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What method are you using to get your data?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Auth does not give you a guarantee that `photoURL` will contain a value.  It can definitely be null, and you should check for that before you try to display it.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a noob mistake and i found a solution.

It was a grammatical or more likely a case sensitive error.

Make sure that when you are setting the data for your storage, keep the name/spelling case same as when you were defining the pairs:

```
class User {
  final String username;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String displayName;
  final String bio;

  User(
      {this.username,
      this.photoUrl,
      this.id,
      this.email,
      this.displayName,
      this.bio});

  factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
      id: doc['id'],
      username: doc['username'],
      email: doc['email'],
      photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
      bio: doc['bio'],
      displayName: doc['displayName'],
    );
  }
}
```

Setting Value for Firebase:

```
 usersRef.document(user.id).setData({
        "id": user.id,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
```